# Approximation of selfadjoint matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, matrix-analysis

We first observe that by spectral theorem of a selfadjoint matrix, any selfadjoint matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ can be written as (up to unitarily equivalence) $A=A_{+}-A_{-}$ where $A_{+}, A_{-}\geq 0$ with $A_{+}A_{-}=0$. Now I have a question which is following:

**Question:** Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a selfadjoint matrix. Does there exist a sequence (or net) $\{A_{\lambda}\}$ where $A_{\lambda}=A_{+}(\lambda)-A_{-}(\lambda)$ with $A_{+}{(\lambda)}\geq 0, A_{-}(\lambda)>0$ and $A_{+}{(\lambda)}A_{-}(\lambda)=0$ s.t. $\lim A_{\lambda}=A$?

Any comment/hint is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Misunderstood the question: I thought $>0$ meant $\geq 0$ and non-zero. It is actually meant as positive definite, which changes things.

This is not true generally. Indeed, suppose that $A = A^* \in M_p$ can be approximated by $A_n$ where $(A_n)_+(A_n)_- = 0$, where $(A_n)_- > 0$ for all $n$. Being positive definite, $(A_n)_-$ has strictly positive eigenvalues, and is therefore invertible. So since $(A_n)_+(A_n)_- = 0$, this implies that $(A_n)_+ = 0$, so $-(A_n)_- = (A_n)_+ - (A_n)_- = A_n \to A = A_+ - A_-$, from which its clear that $A_+$ must be 0, so the positive part of $A$ must be 0.

So if $A$ has a strictly positive eigenvalue, this cannot be done. For example, the 2x2 matrix below cannot be approximated in such a way.

Below is the original answer I put for which I interpreted $> 0$ as $\geq 0$ and non-zero.

Sequences will be good enough since $M_n$ is finite-dimensional. The obvious answer to your question **if there are negative eigenvalues** is to take $A_\lambda = A, A_+(\lambda) = A_+, A_-(\lambda) = A_-$.

The only difference now is that if you have no negative eigenvalues, can you approximate $A_-$ by strictly positive matrices? Yes!

All that's really happening here is that if $A$ is a self-adjoint matrix, its unitarily diagonalizable (actually any normal matrix is), so lets suppose that $A = \lambda_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus \lambda_p \in M_p$. All that your decomposition into $A_+$ and $A_-$ is doing is letting $A_+$ be the diagonal matrix with the positive $\lambda_i$'s, and $A_-$ will be the positive parts of the negative $\lambda_i$'s.

Edit: you can write this out explicitly:
$$A_+ = \max(0,\lambda_1)\oplus \cdots \oplus\max(0,\lambda_p), A_- = \max(0,-\lambda_1)\oplus\cdots\oplus\max(0,-\lambda_p).$$

So if you wanted an approximation, just approximate the eigenvalues in $\mathbb{R}$! For example if
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, $$
we can appriximate it by
$$A_n = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{n}
\end{pmatrix}. $$
Then $(A_n)_-$ will just be $0 \oplus \frac{1}{n}$, which is a matrix $> 0$. You can do the same thing in general for any diagonal matrix.

Comment: in your example ${A_n}_{-}\geq 0$ (not necessarily >0) as if you take $x=(1,0)^t$ then $\langle {(A_n)}_{-}x,x\rangle=0$. I want to draw your attention in the fact that one also needs to approximate $A$ by $A_n$ in such a way that ${(A_n)}_{+}{(A_n)}_{-}=0$.

Comment: In this 2x2 case, $0 \oplus \frac{1}{n} > 0$ since if $y = (0,1)$, then $\langle (A_n)_-y,y\rangle = \frac{1}{n} > 0$. We also have $(A_n)_+(A_n)_- = 0$ since $1 \oplus 0 \perp 0 \oplus 1$, so that $(A_n)_-$ is just a scalar multiple of a projection which is orthogonal to $(A_n)_+$. The same will hold in general since we can assume the matrices are diagonal.

By $B > 0$ we just mean a matrix is positive definite and non-zero, which of course a diagonal matrix with non-negative entries and atleast one strictly positive entry satisfies.

Comment: By the more general part, I maen that $(A_n)_+ = \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_{i_+}p_k$ and $(A_n)_- = \sum_{j=1}^l(\lambda_{j_-}+ \frac{1}{n})q_j$ where $p_i,q_j$ are rank-one projections such that $p_i \perp q_j$ and $\lambda_{i_+},\lambda_{j_-} \geq 0$. The inclusion of $\frac{1}{n}$ ensures that $(A_n)_- > 0$.

Comment: A matrix $A$ is said to be positive definite if $\langle Ax,x\rangle >0$ for all $x$ (not for some $x$). So $0 \oplus \frac{1}{n}\not\gt 0$ as I mentioned before. Moreover the way you defined $(A_n)_{-}\geq 0$ (not >0) as $q_j\geq 0$. ofcourse I agree that $P(A_n)_{-}P>0$ where $P$ is orthogonal projection of $\cup_{j=1}^{l} ran q_j $ but $(A_n)_{-}\not\gt 0$.

Comment: I just wrote something wrong: I said put $\frac{1}{n}$ where ever there is a 0 (this will break $(A_n)_+(A_n)_- = 0$). Let me think about this some more.

Comment: See in the edited part of the answer you are putting $0$ in the diagonal of $(A_n)_{-}$ in the place where eigen values of $A$ are positive. How can it be  stricly positive as we know a symmetric matrix is positive iff all eigen values are strictly positive but according to your construction, 0 may be eigen value $(A_n)_{-}$  if $A$ has atleast one positive eigen value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100759/discussion-between-pstheman-and-piku).